# Default page is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

ASP MVC 1.0 being hosted on IIS 6.

I set up the wildcard filtering already.

When the user visits the root of the site, the home view appears but the jquery is non functional when trying to ajax query Home/SummaryView

If I browse to the actual view url /Home then every thing works.

Works fine in VS with the ASP .Net dev server.

Comment: Sounds like a relative path problem. What does your

    <script src=".....

tag look like that includes jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

="<%= Url.Content("") %>"  turned out to be the proper fix for links under iis 6

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment from David

Try replacing the Jquery script tag with something like this:

```
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Darn you... I was just typing the same thing... +1 from me :-D

Comment: he said that the stuff it's working on VS server, could this really be the issue ?

Comment: Omu- Depends on how the app is deployed to IIS (ex. http://<IIS6Server>/<appname>/)

Answer (score 0):

it could be that your browser's javascript is turned off, you better check that in the first place

Answer (score 0):

also ajax might not work because you have to register a **MIME type for you services** which are used with ajax try typing something like http://localhost/yousite/yourAJAXSERVICE.svc if you don't get an xml on you screen than you surely have to register the **svc MIME TYPE**

Answer (score 0):

The default router is for IIS7 and you must configure your router in the Web.config file for IIS6 to work properly. I suspect that there is a problem with the jquery finding the path.

This should help you with the problem: http://blog.codeville.net/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/